# Beautifulsoup find element by text using `find_all` no matter if there are elements in it

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

For example

```
bs = BeautifulSoup("<html><a>sometext</a></html>")
print bs.find_all("a",text=re.compile(r"some"))
```

returns `[<a>sometext</a>]` but when element searched for has a child, i.e. `img`

```
bs = BeautifulSoup("<html><a>sometext<img /></a></html>")
print bs.find_all("a",text=re.compile(r"some"))
```

it returns `[]`

Is there a way to use `find_all` to match the later example?

Comment: The `find_all` works as expected, it is the `re.compile()` that is preventing any results from coming back.

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa: `bs.find_all('a', text=lambda e: print(e))` prints out `None` when I test it for some reason.

Comment: Perhaps BeautifulSoup assumes that an element either has text, or child elements, but not both. `print bs.find_all("a",text=True)` returns [].

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will need to use a hybrid approach since `text=` will fail when an element has child elements as well as text.

```
bs = BeautifulSoup("<html><a>sometext</a></html>")    
reg = re.compile(r'some')
elements = [e for e in bs.find_all('a') if reg.match(e.text)]
```

#### Background

When BeautifulSoup is searching for an element, and `text` is a callable, it eventually [eventually calls](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L1267):

```
self._matches(found.string, self.text)
```

In the two examples you gave, the `.string` method returns different things:

```
>>> bs1 = BeautifulSoup("<html><a>sometext</a></html>")
>>> bs1.find('a').string
u'sometext'
>>> bs2 = BeautifulSoup("<html><a>sometext<img /></a></html>")
>>> bs2.find('a').string
>>> print bs2.find('a').string
None
```

The `.string` method looks like this:

```
@property
def string(self):
    """Convenience property to get the single string within this tag.

    :Return: If this tag has a single string child, return value
     is that string. If this tag has no children, or more than one
     child, return value is None. If this tag has one child tag,
     return value is the 'string' attribute of the child tag,
     recursively.
    """
    if len(self.contents) != 1:
        return None
    child = self.contents[0]
    if isinstance(child, NavigableString):
        return child
    return child.string
```

If we print out the contents we can see why this returns `None`:

```
>>> print bs1.find('a').contents
[u'sometext']
>>> print bs2.find('a').contents
[u'sometext', <img/>]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, that was my conclusion, also. Wondering if I have overlooked something, suppose I didn't.