# BeautifulSoup scanning HTML by tags, attributes, RegEx, and iterating

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am expecting the code:

```
html = """
<th scope="row">Fruits<br />
<i><a href="#Fruits">Buy</a></i></th>
<td><a href="banana.html" color="yellow">Banana</a><br />
    <a href="kiwi.html" color="green">Kiwi</a><br />
    <a href="Persimmon" color="orange">Persimmon</a><br />
</tr>
"""

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

th_node = soup.find('th', { 'scope' : 'row' }, text = re.compile('^Fruits'))
td_node = th_node.find('td')
fruits = td_node.find_all('a')
for f in fruits:
    print f['color'], " ", f.text
```

To print:

```
yellow banana
green kiwi
orange Persimmon
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing wrong because:

```
th_node = soup.find('th', { 'scope' : 'row' }, text = re.compile('^Fruits'))
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16090520/5299236):

> You will need to use a hybrid approach since `text=`will fail when an element has child elements as well as text.

And for example:

```
>>> a = '<th scope="row">foo</th>'
>>> b = '<th scope="row">foo<td>bar</td></th>'
>>> BeautifulSoup(a, "html.parser").find('th', {'scope': 'row'}, text='foo')
<th scope="row">foo</th>

>>> BeautifulSoup(b, "html.parser").find('th', {'scope': 'row'}, text='foo')
>>> BeautifulSoup(b, "html.parser").find('th', {'scope': 'row'}, text='foobar')
```

See, BeautifulSoup failed when there's `td` tag in `th` tag. So we need(the idea also from that answer):

```
html = """
<th scope="row">Fruits<br />
<i><a href="#Fruits">Buy</a></i></th>
<td><a href="banana.html" color="yellow">Banana</a><br />
    <a href="kiwi.html" color="green">Kiwi</a><br />
    <a href="Persimmon" color="orange">Persimmon</a><br />
</tr>
"""

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

reg = re.compile(r'^Fruits')
th_node = [e for e in soup.find_all(
    'th', {'scope': 'row'}) if reg.search(e.text)][0]

print th_node
```

Output:

```
<th scope="row">Fruits<br/>
<i><a href="#Fruits">Buy</a></i></th>
```

Yeah, this isn't you want because that `td` tag isn't inside the `th` tag. So now we can use [`tag.find_next()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) method like this:

```
html = """
<th scope="row">Fruits<br />
<i><a href="#Fruits">Buy</a></i></th>
<td><a href="banana.html" color="yellow">Banana</a><br />
    <a href="kiwi.html" color="green">Kiwi</a><br />
    <a href="Persimmon" color="orange">Persimmon</a><br />
</tr>
"""

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

reg = re.compile(r'^Fruits')
th_node = [e for e in soup.find_all(
    'th', {'scope': 'row'}) if reg.search(e.text)][0]

td_node = th_node.find_next('td')
fruits = td_node.find_all('a')

for f in fruits:
    print f['color'], " ", f.text
```

Output:

```
yellow   Banana
green   Kiwi
orange   Persimmon
```

Then we done!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attrs` only(simply) or mix of `lambda` and `attrs` if you need `text` node value to be checked as below-

```
 html = """
    <th scope="row">Fruits<br />
    <i><a href="#Fruits">Buy</a></i></th>
    <td><a href="banana.html" color="yellow">Banana</a><br />
        <a href="kiwi.html" color="green">Kiwi</a><br />
        <a href="Persimmon" color="orange">Persimmon</a><br />
    </tr>
    """

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

th_node = soup.find('th', { 'scope' : 'row' })#OR th_node = soup.find('th', { 'scope' : 'row' },lambda x: x.text.startswith('Fruits'))
td_node = th_node.findNext('td')
fruits = td_node.find_all('a')
for f in fruits:
    print f['color'], " ", f.text
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `class` to `href` element and correct source code is below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = ""
html += "<table><th scope='row'>Fruits<br /><i><a href='#Fruits'>Buy</a></i></th>"
html += "<tr><td><a class='fruits' href='banana.html' color='yellow'>Banana</a><br/>"
html += "<a class='fruits' href='kiwi.html' color='green'>Kiwi</a><br/>"
html += "<a class='fruits' href='Persimmon' color='orange'>Persimmon</a><br/>"
html += "</tr></table>"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
for link in soup.findAll('a',{'class':'fruits'}):
    col = link.get('color')
    name = link.string
    print(col + " " + name)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because `beautifulsoup` is comparing your regex against nothing:

```
>>> def f(s):
...     print "comparing", s
... 
>>> soup.find("th", text=f)
comparing None
None
```